How do I take faster screenshots using C#?
I'm writing an app to automate some gameplay elements of a rhythm game (and for those curious, I've already beaten it, so this is more of a programming challenge rather than a cheat tool). I've got it working in general, but the issue I'm having is that the screenshots I take of the play field takes too long (mostly 16'ish ms, but sometimes 30'ish ms), which limits its usability on high-BPM songs.
Are there any faster ways to take screenshots or some other methods that might suit my needs? Preferably I'd want to hit at least 8'ish ms on the 50x150px area, although if I can get even quicker that'd enable me to do checks that I can't do right now due to time constraints in the screenshotting part.
Right now I'm using Graphics.CopyFromScreen, limiting its capture area to a small section (roughly 50x150px). From googling, I also found a method using BitBlt which seems to be way faster (taking essentially zero time), but it doesn't seem to work as it should (and I don't think it's related to my code; when I take a screenshot using that method, the first time I get the current screen, but all subsequent screenshots made returns the first screen again, even if I restart my own program; it only serves a new screenshot after I restart the game).
Most of the code regarding the screenshots have been lifted straight from other examples, but I've made a couple of modifications myself to make them suit my needs better.
    public static Bitmap CaptureImage(IntPtr handle, Rectangle? coords)
    {
        Rectangle bounds;
        Rect rect = new Rect();
        GetWindowRect(handle, ref rect);

        if (coords == null)
            bounds = new Rectangle(rect.Left, rect.Top, rect.Right - rect.Left, rect.Bottom - rect.Top);
        else
            bounds = new Rectangle(rect.Left+coords.Value.X, rect.Top+coords.Value.Y, coords.Value.Width, coords.Value.Height);

        Bitmap result = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height);

        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(result))
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            g.CopyFromScreen(new Point(bounds.Left, bounds.Top), Point.Empty, bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Time to take screenshot: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }

        return result;
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmapAt(Point location, int width, int height)
    {
        Bitmap sImg = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        using (Graphics gsrc = Graphics.FromHwnd(windowHandle))
        {
            using (Graphics gdest = Graphics.FromImage(sImg))
            {
                IntPtr hSrcDC = gsrc.GetHdc();
                IntPtr hDC = gdest.GetHdc();
                int retval = BitBlt(hDC, 0, 0, width, height, hSrcDC, location.X, location.Y, (int)CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
                gdest.ReleaseHdc();
                gsrc.ReleaseHdc();
            }
            gsrc.Dispose();
        }
        return sImg;
    }


If the intent is to "capture the app", then you should capture "the visuals" of the app; and not the screen. Visuals don't even have to be "on screen".  In WPF / UWP you can select any part of the visual tree, and capture it as an image. You could be doing this async in the background; even moving "forward".

Also,  measuring performance / speed with StopWatch might give you skewed readings. Maybe it's worthwhile to fire up a benchmarkdotnet, that's actually fit for evaluating improvements.

@GerrySchmitz Wouldn’t this only work if the app you’re capturing is also WPF/UWP or at least win32 UI or something? For games, especially a high-performance rhythm game, we are probably talking about something that is directly drawing to the screen (e.g. DirectX or OpenGL).

You would need to copy the graphics buffer directly. That would involve some Direct3D API calls which are not so easy to get right. You should check out a video recording tool like OBS (https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio?tab=readme-ov-file) which should be a good example how this can be done in an efficient and reliable way.

@GerrySchmitz, how would I go about to capture the visuals of the game? I'm assuming I'd have to get the internal objects of the game somehow? Also, I'm not sure it even is done in WPF/UWP, they're using Unity as the engine of the game (even though UWP can be used in Unity).

There is many tools, even open source, out there to capture video of a screen. You might wanna look at how they do it.

I agree with Alois Kraus. Games will most likely use Direct3D, or possibly openGL/Vulcan. High performance capture would need to interact with this directly, and C# is not great tool for this, since you cannot just import a header file. There are some Direct3D wrappers for c#, but I don't think any are maintained anymore.
